# Sql Update with Joins is failing

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this query and am getting back an error displaying "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM Sales JOIN Sales ON Inventory.saleID=Sales.ID JOIN Customers ON Sales.custo' at line 1

Here is my Query. I know i am not using aliases so it looks ugly but the syntax seems correct and the variables im passing in are not null I have echoed them back.

```
 $sql = "UPDATE Sales SET salequantity='$takeCount' 
       FROM `Sales` 
       JOIN Sales ON Inventory.saleID=Sales.ID 
       JOIN Customers ON Sales.customerID=Customers.ID 
       JOIN Products ON Inventory.productID = Products.ID 
      JOIN Categories ON Products.categoryID=Categories.ID 
      WHERE Customers.ID='$customersID' AND Products.ID='$id'";
```

Here is my schema

```
CREATE TABLE Categories
(
ID int NOT NULL auto_increment,
type varchar(255),
description varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Products
(
ID int NOT NULL auto_increment,
categoryID int,
customerID int,
name varchar(255),
description varchar(255),
price float(10),
quantity int(10),
PRIMARY KEY (ID),
FOREIGN KEY (categoryID) REFERENCES Categories(ID)
);
CREATE TABLE Customers
(
ID int NOT NULL auto_increment,
productID int,
name varchar(255),
street varchar(255),
city varchar(255),
state varchar(255),
zip int(8),
username varchar(255),
password varchar(255),
confirm_password varchar(255),
phone varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (ID),
);

CREATE TABLE Sales
(
ID int NOT NULL auto_increment,
customerID int,
amount float(15),
salequantity int(10),
PRIMARY KEY (ID),
FOREIGN KEY (customerID) REFERENCES Customers(ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Inventory
(
productID int,
saleID int,
FOREIGN KEY (productID) REFERENCES Products(ID),
FOREIGN KEY (saleID) REFERENCES Sales(ID)
);
```

Here is the final query. Just want this simple one to work.

```
UPDATE Sales  INNER JOIN Sales ON Inventory.saleID=Sales.ID SET salequantity=2 where Sales.customerID=1 AND Inventory.productID=1;
```

Ran query from 1st comment and failed as well.

```
UPDATE Sales SET salequantity=5 FROM Sales JOIN Inventory ON Inventory.saleID=Sales.ID JOIN Customers ON Sales.customerID=Customers.ID JOIN Products ON Inventory.productID = Products.ID JOIN Categories ON Products.categoryID=Categories.ID where Customers.ID=1 AND Products.ID=1;
```

Solution
Aggregate Function this works perfectly

```
$customerProducts = mysql_query("select Products.ID, Products.name, Products.description, Products.quantity,Products.price, Categories.type, Sales.ID, Sales.customerID, Sales.amount, Sales.salequantity, Inventory.productID, Inventory.saleID, Customers.ID, Customers.productID, COUNT(Products.name) AS productsCount from(((( Inventory INNER JOIN Sales ON Inventory.saleID=Sales.ID) JOIN Customers ON Sales.customerID=Customers.ID) JOIN Products ON Inventory.productID = Products.ID) JOIN Categories ON Products.categoryID=Categories.ID) where Customers.ID ='$customersID' GROUP BY Products.name");
```

Comment: i could be wrong, but set comes at the end after a join

Comment: Please create a fiddle with schema

Comment: @JustinWeinzimmer also please finalize your question with the exact query

Comment: please note that table aliases reign supreme with updates on self. You need to refer to the table as a different alias

Answer (score 0):

**Schema**

```
create table sales (id varchar(10), customerid varchar(10), salequantity varchar(10))
create table Inventory (id varchar(10), productID varchar(10), saleID varchar(10))
create table Customers (id varchar(10))
create table Products (id varchar(10), categoryID varchar(10))
create table Categories (id varchar(10))
```

**Corrected Query**

```
UPDATE Sales SET salequantity='$takeCount' 
  FROM Sales JOIN Inventory ON Inventory.saleID=Sales.ID
             JOIN Customers ON Sales.customerID=Customers.ID
             JOIN Products ON Inventory.productID = Products.ID
             JOIN Categories ON Products.categoryID=Categories.ID
  where Customers.ID='$customersID' AND Products.ID='$id'
```

**Output**

(0 row(s) affected)

**Change To Query**

In first join actual query was like "FROM `Sales` JOIN Sales ON Inventory.saleID=Sales.ID", corrected this to "FROM `Sales` 
       JOIN **Inventory** ON Inventory.saleID=Sales.ID ". It is not clear what exactly is your desired output. But above query will solve the compilation error.

Comment: Just tried the query and got the same error. This is what i used in mysql     UPDATE Sales SET salequantity=5 FROM Sales JOIN Inventory ON Inventory.saleID=Sales.ID JOIN Customers ON Sales.customerID=Customers.ID JOIN Products ON Inventory.productID = Products.ID JOIN Categories ON Products.categoryID=Categories.ID where Customers.ID=1 AND Products.ID=1

Comment: i protest. Why is sales being updated this way. Sales should have an insert. Sales are inserted, not updated :>

Comment: The insert has already occured i need to update the quantity with the count of products taken in each sale so i took a count and am now setting it with each sale

Comment: set it on the insert.

Comment: it is a question of state of the database. you are leaving the database wrong even if momentarily

Answer (score 0):

```
$customerProducts = mysql_query("select Products.ID, Products.name, Products.description, Products.quantity,Products.price, Categories.type, Sales.ID, Sales.customerID, Sales.amount, Sales.salequantity, Inventory.productID, Inventory.saleID, Customers.ID, Customers.productID, COUNT(Products.name) AS productsCount from(((( Inventory INNER JOIN Sales ON Inventory.saleID=Sales.ID) JOIN Customers ON Sales.customerID=Customers.ID) JOIN Products ON Inventory.productID = Products.ID) JOIN Categories ON Products.categoryID=Categories.ID) where Customers.ID ='$customersID' GROUP BY Products.name");
```

This did exactly what i was looking for. I tried to make it to complicated and forgot about aggregates.